# How to get files from sharepoint folder/link using python?

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint

I am trying to get files in sharepoint folder. The link is something like this: https://mycompany365.sharepoint.com/sites/Projectname/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I tried:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

requests.get("https://mycompany365.sharepoint.com/sites/Projectname/", 
auth=HttpNtlmAuth('\\email','password'))
```

besides that I also tried:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print ("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))

else:
  print (ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

The first code produced 403 error

the second one "An error occurred while retrieving token: AADSTS53003: Blocked by conditional access."

Can someone help me?